# Error de un require_once desde linux

Tags: php, linux

Hace unos dias me instale ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, pero al iniciar mi aplicaion WEB me sale un error que no me pasaba en windows utilizo xampp aunque el linux esta guardado como lampp este es el mensaje de error:

```
Warning: require_once(config/bd.php): Failed to open stream: No existe el archivo o el directorio in /opt/lampp/htdocs/MVC-BITACORA/index.php on line 3

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required 'config/bd.php' (include_path='.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/MVC-BITACORA/index.php:3 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/MVC-BITACORA/index.php on line 3
```

esto solo trantando de abrir el index.php agradesco cualquier ayuda pongo el codigo de mi index.php:

```
<?php

require_once('config/bd.php');
require_once('views/includes/header.php');

require_once('controllers/tareas/general_controller.php');
if (isset($_GET['id_t'])) {
    require_once('controllers/tareas/editar_controller.php');
}
if (isset($_GET['id_a'])) {
    require_once('controllers/tareas/editar_controller.php');
}

require_once('views/includes/footer.php');
?>
```

Comment: El mensaje es claro, PHP no encuentra el archivo. Revisa que la ruta es correcta y que la carpeta `config` está en el mismo nivel que `index.php`.

Comment: `Linux` es OS sensible a mayusculas y minúsculas (eg: `case sensitive`). Verifica que el nombre del directorio y archivo esten todos en minúsculas.

Comment: Si me ha funcionado no sabia que tenia que poner las mayusculas muchas gracias si deseas puedes ponerlo como respuesta para poder marcarlo como respuesta @Marcos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Linux` ([a diferencia de `Windows`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/wsl/case-sensitivity#differences-between-windows-and-linux-case-sensitivity)) es sistema operativo sensible a mayusculas y minúsculas (eg: `case sensitive`).

Una solución a tu problema es validar que los nombres de directorios y archivos esten **todos en minúsculas**.